# jQuery relendo no Select

Tags: php

**jQuery**

```
$("#idRede").on("change", function () {                   

    $.ajax({
        url: "_scripts/_php/_validacoes/buscarDadosRegioes.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
              idRede: $("#idRede").val()
        },
        beforeSend: function() {
            $("#imgCarregando").css('display','block');
        },
        success: function (result) {
            $("#imgCarregando").css('display','none');

            if (result == null){
                $("#idRegiao").append("<option value=>Sem Regiões</option>");
            } else {
                result.forEach(function(option){
                    $("#idRegiao").append("<option value=" + option["idRegiao"] + ">" + option["nome"] + "</option>")
                });
            }
        }

    });

});
```

**buscarDadosRegioes.php**

```
 <?php

    require_once "../../../config.php";

    $regioes = $regioesDao->pesquisaRegioesParametro("idRede", $_POST["idRede"]);

    $options = null;
    $i = 0;

    if ($regioes != null) {

            foreach ($regioes as $regiao):

                $options[$i]["idRegiao"] = $regiao->getIdRegiao();
                $options[$i]["nome"]     = $regiao->getNome();
                $i++;

            endforeach;

    }

    echo json_encode($options);

?>
```

Quando o **array** `$redes` retorna `null`, a linha `echo json_encode($options);` retorna `null`.

E, analogamente, quando o retorno é um **array de objetos**, então o **php** retorna um **array de objetos**. Nada de anormal até aqui.

O problema está no **jQuery** que quando o **result** é `null` (testado com **alert**), então o jQuery continua populando o select com os dados antigos de uma consulta anterior que trouxe resultado mais a linha de quando o **result** da `null`.

Onde estará o erro?

Parece que ele vai guardando os `appends` anteriores e somando tudo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando tu usa o `append`, vai sempre ir adicionando novos resultados sem afetar os anteriores.

O que tu precisa fazer é remover os anteriores antes de adicionar novos resultados.

```
$('#idRegiao').find('option').remove();
```

Código completo:

```
$("#idRede").on("change", function () {                   
    $.ajax({
        url: "_scripts/_php/_validacoes/buscarDadosRegioes.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
              idRede: $("#idRede").val()
        },
        beforeSend: function() {
            $("#imgCarregando").css('display','block');
        },
        success: function (result) {
            $("#imgCarregando").css('display','none');

            $('#idRegiao').find('option').remove();

            if (result == null){
                $("#idRegiao").append("<option value=>Sem Regiões</option>");
            } else {
                result.forEach(function(option){
                    $("#idRegiao").append("<option value=" + option["idRegiao"] + ">" + option["nome"] + "</option>")
                });
            }
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Para o seu javascript eu sugeriria algo como abaixo, pois vi que você tem dificuldades para gerar código html dentro do javascript.

```
$("#idRede").on("change", function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "_scripts/_php/_validacoes/buscarDadosRegioes.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            idRede: $("#idRede").val()
        },
        beforeSend: function () {
            $("#imgCarregando").css('display', 'block');
        },
        success: function (result) {
            $("#imgCarregando").css('display', 'none');
            var option;
            if (result === null) {
                option = document.createElement("option");
                option.textContent = "Sem Regiões";
                $("#idRegiao").append(option);
            } else {
                result.forEach(function (option) {
                    option = document.createElement("option");
                    option.value = option["idRegiao"];
                    option.textContent = option["idRegiao"];
                    $("#idRegiao").append(option);
                    option = null;
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Para o PHP tem algumas questões sintáticas que podem estar te atrapalhando.

```
<?php
require_once "../../../config.php";

$regioes = $regioesDao->pesquisaRegioesParametro("idRede", $_POST["idRede"]);

$i = 0;
$options = [];

if ($regioes != null) {
    foreach ($regioes as $regiao) {
        $options[$i]["idRegiao"] = $regiao->getIdRegiao();
        $options[$i]["nome"][$i] = $regiao->getNome();
    }
}

echo json_encode($options);
?>
```

Se puder mostrar como acontece dentro do método pesquisaRegioesParametro, pois dependendo do modo de fetch que estiver utilizando, o foreach pode alterar a forma de acessar o array de retorno.

Tente isto, qualquer coisa coloque o erro e eu ediyo a minha resposta.